# Timer 2 interrupt with ATmega328p and make measurement in ISR

Tags: arduino-uno, interrupt, atmega328

I am working in my project and i want to use Timer2 interrupt every 100ms to get new measurement from the output of my 5 sensors which connected to pins A1,A2,A3,A4,A5.

I read in some article that using delay instruction is not as good as using timers'Interruptions so, I tried this code put it didn't work properly :

```C++
void setup(){

cli();

  TCCR2A = 0;
  TCCR2B = 0;
  TCNT2  = 0;
  OCR2A = 99;
  TCCR2A |= (1 << WGM21);
  TCCR2B |= (1 << CS21);   
  TIMSK2 |= (1 << OCIE2A);
sei();

Serial.begin(9600);  
}
void loop()
{
Serial.print(digitalRead(1));
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(digitalRead(2));
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(digitalRead(3));
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(digitalRead(4));
Serial.print(' ');
Serial.print(digitalRead(5));
Serial.println(' ');

}
```

Comment: Where is your ISR?

Comment: in fact I dont know where i put the ISR interupt service routine where i have to put measurement instruction .

Comment: Enabling the interrupt without writing a ISR is pointless.

Comment: i know that but where  in the code i put the ISR?I think i have to put it in the loop

Comment: `i want to use Timer2 interrupt every 100ms to get new measurement from the output of my 5 sensors which connected to pins A1,A2,A3,A4,A5.` - your code does not reflect those intentions.

Comment: yes i mean i want to see in my screen new measurement every 100ms ,
I don't want to use delay instruction.

Comment: I am sorry mr nick put i know more in 8051 cause we use assembly but in arduino it's hard.

Comment: Before trying to use an ISR, why not start with [simple things](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay)?

Comment: `ISR(TIMER2_COMPA_vect){ ..code here.. }`. However with your current setting the ISR gets called once every 0.5ms.

Answer (score 1):

Well let's start from the start ...

---

### Analog readings

> to get new measurement from the output of my 5 sensors which connected to pins A1,A2,A3,A4,A5.

```C++
Serial.print(digitalRead(1));
```

That is not reading **analog** pin A1, it is reading **digital** pin 1. If you want to read A1 you need:

```C++
Serial.print(analogRead(1));
```

---

### Check the time

By far the simplest thing would be to simply check the time and take a reading when 100 ms is up.

Example:

```C++
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);  
}  // end of setup

unsigned long lastReading;
const unsigned long INTERVAL = 100;  // ms

void loop()
{

  // is time up?
  if (millis () - lastReading >= INTERVAL)
    {
    lastReading = millis ();  // when we took this reading
    Serial.print(analogRead(1));
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(analogRead(2));
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(analogRead(3));
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(analogRead(4));
    Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(analogRead(5));
    Serial.println();
    }  // end of if time up

  // do other things here

}  // end of loop
```

I increased the baud rate to 115200. Why use 9600 when you are trying to print 5 x 4 characters every 100 ms?

---

### Using timers

If you really want to use timers (and I don't see what they achieve here) I have a [page about timers](http://www.gammon.com.au/timers) that describes using them, and interrupts, in some depth.

The very least you would need is a timer 2 "compare A" interrupt like this:

```C++
ISR (TIMER2_COMPA_vect) 
  {
  // Timer 2 has reached its comparison value
  }
```